# List of DOMDocument::loadXML error messages

Tags: php, xml

I am using `DOMDocument::loadXML` followed by `error_get_last()` in the event of corruption in the processed XML.  Is there an available list of error messages that the `loadXML` might generate?  I have tried grepping in the PHP and libxml source code, currently without success.

(Edit: Hunting around in the libxml2 source code has revealed error messages being produced / formatted in parser.c.  They are throughout the code, and possibly only some are generated here, so a definitive list would be helpful.)

Answer (score 1):

http://www.xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-xmlerror.html

?

Comment: That gives a list of the error codes but `error_get_last()` is returning an error message.

Comment: ... and the other information provided by `error_get_last()` does not provide details of the particular XML issue.